# Regular expression to match and extract a long domain

Tags: python, regex

I want to match and extract a domain name. I have the following line of code:

```
result = re.findall(r"(^((?!-))(xn--)?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{0,1}\.(xn--)?([a-z0-9\-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-z]{2,})$)", text)
```

It does work well for domains like `example.org`, `example.org.eu`. But it does not work for domains like `sub_example.example.org.eu`.

Comment: Try [`^(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]?\.)+(?:xn--)?(?:[a-z0-9-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-z]{2,})$`](https://regex101.com/r/w1ct5E/3) with `re.findall` (I removed all capturing groups so you do not need to wrap it with parentheses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding and pruning your pattern, the pattern you may use to match the third type of strings is

```
^(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]?\.)+(?:xn--)?(?:[a-z0-9-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-z]{2,})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w1ct5E/3).

The main point is that I wrapped the `(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]?\.` part with a non-capturing group and quantified it with `+` (one or more repetitions).

Note you may use it with `re.findall` directly as I removed all capturing groups so you do not need to wrap it with parentheses.

You do not need the first `(?!-)` as the next consuming pattern does not match a hyphen, so I removed it.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]?\.)+` - 1 or more sequences of

  - `(?:xn--)?` - an  optional `xn--` substring
  - `[a-z0-9]` - a lowercase ASCII letter or digit
  - `[a-z0-9-_]{0,61}` - 0 to 61 lowercase ASCII letters, digits, `-` or `_`
  - `[a-z0-9]?` - an optional lowercase ASCII letter or digit
  - `\.` - a dot
- `(?:xn--)?` - an optional `xn--` string
- `(?:[a-z0-9-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-z]{2,})` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `[a-z0-9-]{1,61}` - 1 to 61 lowercase ASCII letters, `-` or digits
  - `|` - or
  - `[a-z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-z]{2,}` - 1 to 30  lowercase ASCII letters, `-` or digits, a dot and two  lowercase ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer and  details about regex!